# Linq - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, csv

I currently have a program that uses Linq to read a CSV file.  Everything was working great until a recent change was done where the CSV file had records being added to it where the last 2 columns where empty.

So, the error I am getting now is Index was outside the bounds of the array.  The question I have is how do I handle a column where an empty or null value is set in the CSV file?

Here's my abbreviated code below.  Thanks for any help in advance.

```
Function readLINQ(ByVal strCustomerFile As String) As DataTable

    Dim readlines = File.ReadAllLines(strCustomerFile)
    File.WriteAllLines(strCustomerFile, readlines.Skip(4).ToArray())

    Dim gTable As New DataTable("CashFile")
    With gTable
        .Columns.Add("Num").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("EnvNum").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("TransNum").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("Envelope").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("RemitterName").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("InvoiceNumber").DataType = GetType(System.String)

    End With
    Dim lines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strCustomerFile)
    Dim pattern As String = ",(?=(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))"



    Dim r As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern)
    Dim custs = From line In lines Where line <> header AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
                Let data = r.Split(line)
                Select New With {.Num = data(0), .EnvNum = data(1), .TransNum = data(2), .Envelope = data(3), .RemitterName = data(4), .InvoiceNumber = data(5)}

    Dim xRow As DataRow
    For Each row In custs
        xRow = gTable.NewRow()
        xRow.ItemArray = {row.Num, row.EnvNum, row.TransNum, row.Envelope, _
                          row.RemitterName, row.InvoiceNumber}

        gTable.Rows.Add(xRow)
    Next

    readlines = Nothing
    lines = Nothing

    Return gTable
End Function
```

Comment: have you seen the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` class?

Comment: First I'd heard of that class.  I'm looking at something now that seems promising. However, I'm getting all information stuffed in one column rather than spread out individually.

Comment: Using parser As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(strcustomerfile)
            parser.SetDelimiters(",")
            While Not parser.EndOfData
                gTable.Rows.Add(parser.ReadLine())
            End While
        End Using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use

```
Let data = r.Split(line + ",,")
```

by which you add two empty entries add the end of each line. They are ignored for lines with 6 entries and for lines with 4 entries they add two empty entries, so `data(4)` and `data(5)` are not out of bounds.

This causes RemitterName and InvoiceNumber to be empty strings. I assume that is what should happen when the last 2 columns are absent.

Comment: It's a mixed bag at this point.  I have 20 records where all the columns have values.  However the last 10 records are where the RemitterName and InvoiceNumber don't have anything.  I think I did get a viable solution working using the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser class.

Comment: That's what I was aiming at. But anyhow, `TextFieldParser` sounds like a more solid solution.

Comment: Gert, I just wanted to say thanks again for your tip.  I tested this out as I have a new issue with the TextFieldParser erroring out with a "The directory is not empty." error when the program is doing cleanup with the extracted folder created from the .zip file I work with.  I'm having to to work with LINQ as it seems to be the only one that doesn't get hung up with this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up being a viable alternative solution.  I posted all of the columns here so it may be a bit long.  Hope this helps someone down the road.

```
Function TextFieldReadCSV(ByVal strCustomerFile As String) As DataTable

    'need to skip 4 lines
    Dim readlines = File.ReadAllLines(strCustomerFile)
    File.WriteAllLines(strcustomerfile, readlines.Skip(4).ToArray())

    Dim gTable As New DataTable("CashFile")
    With gTable
        .Columns.Add("Num").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("EnvNum").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("TransNum").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("Envelope").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("TID").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("TransUID").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("Lockbox").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("Date").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("Time").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("Batch").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("BatchItem").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("TransSource").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("Group").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("GroupName").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("Amount").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("ABART").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("AccountNum").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("CheckNum").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("NumImages").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("CheckImage").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("CheckBack").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("EnvelopeImage").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("EnvelopeBack").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("InvoiceImage").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("InvoiceBack").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("AllPageImages").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("AllPageBack").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("RemitterName").DataType = GetType(System.String)
        .Columns.Add("InvoiceNumber").DataType = GetType(System.String)

    End With

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(strCustomerFile)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData

            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            Dim currentField As String

            Dim FieldArray(28) As String
            Dim i = 0
            For Each currentField In currentRow
                FieldArray(i) = currentField
                i = i + 1
            Next

            Dim xRow As DataRow

            xRow = gTable.NewRow()
            xRow.ItemArray = {FieldArray(0), FieldArray(1), FieldArray(2), FieldArray(3), FieldArray(4), FieldArray(5), FieldArray(6), FieldArray(7), _
                              FieldArray(8), FieldArray(9), FieldArray(10), FieldArray(11), FieldArray(12), FieldArray(13), FieldArray(14), FieldArray(15), _
                              FieldArray(16), FieldArray(17), FieldArray(18), FieldArray(19), FieldArray(20), FieldArray(21), FieldArray(22), _
                              FieldArray(23), FieldArray(24), FieldArray(25), FieldArray(26), FieldArray(27), FieldArray(28)}

            gTable.Rows.Add(xRow)

        End While
    End Using

    Return gTable
End Function
```

Comment: I had issues with using the TextFieldParser class when my program was doing cleanup work with deleted extracted zip files where it has to retrieve a csv file.  The code above doesn't reflect where I added MyReader.Close() and MyReader.Dispose()...it still would error out trying to delete the extracted folder with "The directory is not empty.".  I've had that error show up before for other methods I tested with...LINQ seems to be the only one where it's a nonissue.